# iphone camera view with a custom size

Tags: iphone, uiview, camera

I need to have a preview of the camera but not in fullscreen. Actually I need to resize the camera view to manage place for my overlay view.
I need a resize camera view and not a truncated one.

Do you have any ideas/pointers to achieve this?

Thanks for your help :)

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `cameraViewTransform` property of the UIImagePickerController.